# Android Desire HD Bitmap Scaling

Tags: bitmap, scaling, android

I've build a custom camera activity where the user can take a picture. The picture is saved in the external storage directory via the picture callback. The user is then redirected to another activity where he can preview the picture. Before the preview is shown, the picture is scaled down in a seperate thread to a certain maximum dimension. Here is the scaling code:

```
byte[] tempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

int oldWidth = options.outWidth;
int oldHeight = options.outHeight;

if (oldWidth > MAX_DIM || oldHeight > MAX_DIM) {

    Logger.i(Constants.SCALE_TAG, "Must scale picture");
    int scaleFactor = getScaleFactor(oldWidth, oldHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    options.inTempStorage = tempStorage;
    System.gc();
    newB = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

} else {

    Logger.i(Constants.SCALE_TAG, "No need for scaling");

    // We do not need to scale the picture, it is small
    // enough.
    System.gc();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inTempStorage = tempStorage;
    if (!stop) {
        newB = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
    } else {
        return;
    }

}
```

Here is the code that calculates the scaling factor:

```
private int getScaleFactor(int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {

    // Holds the raw scale factor.
    float rawScale;

    // Get the scaling factor.
    if (oldWidth >= oldHeight) {
        rawScale = 1.0F / ((MAX_DIM * 1.0F) / (oldWidth * 1.0F));
    } else {
        rawScale = 1.0F / ((MAX_DIM * 1.0F) / (oldHeight * 1.0F)); 
    }
    Logger.i(Constants.SCALE_TAG, "Raw scale factor: " + rawScale);
    return Math.round(rawScale);

}
```

This code works fine on most devices, but somehow the Desire HD won't correctly scale the picture. It looks like he takes the original picture and duplicates it thirty times or so and squizes it into the Bitmap, causing a weird stripe-like picture. Does anyone know of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use less memory. The problem is you're using too much memory.